# What do you call an Android control that slides up

Tags: android

I'm thinking of something like this in material design:

[image]

Say you tap something, and a full width display overlays the content for about a third of the page.

I'm sure I've seen this type of thing before, but I've got no idea what it's called. Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called **Bottom Sheets**.

Check it out [here](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-sheets.html)

Comment: Yep, that's what I was thinking of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for is `BottomSheet` from support library 23.2